# Проблемы с запросом SELECT...WHERE

Tags: c++, sql, qt, postgresql

имеется такая схема

```
create table "Messenger".public.group
(
    id       serial primary key,
    name     varchar(32) unique not null,
    password varchar(128)       not null
);
```

заполнено следующими значениями

```
6,main,1234
7,new life,1234
8,lions,1234
```

когда запрашиваю данные в Qt таким кодом, то получаю все пароли

```
QSqlQuery query(conn);
query.exec("select * from \"Messenger\".public.group");
while (query.next()) {
   qDebug() << query.value("password").toString();
}
```

но когда хочу получить пароль определенной группы, запрос выдает ничего

```
QSqlQuery query(conn);
query.exec("select * from \"Messenger\".public.group where name = 'main'");
while (query.next()) {
    qDebug() << query.value("password").toString();
}
```

кто знает как пофиксить запрос с `where`?

Comment: `name LIKE 'main'`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin = операция не поддерживается что ли для строк там

Comment: А там это где? ) Какая субд?

Comment: postgres, через консоль запрос делаю ок, конечно же работает, но через Qt че то не идет

Comment: А ошибку пишет? `query.lastError()`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin пробовал, пустая строка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` в `PostgreSQL` это зарезервированное кодовое слово и чтобы использовать в качестве имени столбца его необходимо заключить в двойные кавычки:

```
QSqlQuery query(conn);
query.exec("select * from \"Messenger\".public.group where \"name\" = 'main'");
while (query.next()) {
    qDebug() << query.value("password").toString();
}
```